# How to change one bootstrap datetimepicker value based on another bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript

```js
function setCheckOutDate(){ 
var str1 = document.getElementById("checkInDate").value; document.getElementById("checkOutDate").value=str1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
            <td colspan="16" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;"><label class="control-label">Enter Check In Date:</label></td>
            <td colspan="16">
            <div class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input size="16" name="checkInDate" id="checkInDate" type="text" value="" readonly style="height:30px;" onchange="setCheckOutDate();">
                <span class="add-on" style="height:30px;"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <span class="add-on" style="height:30px;"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
            </td>
        </div>
  
    
        <div class="control-group">
            <td colspan="16" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;"><label class="control-label">Enter Check Out Date:</label></td>
            <td colspan="16">
            <div class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input3" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input size="16" name="checkOutDate" id="checkOutDate" type="text" style="height:30px;" value="" readonly onchange="showRoomBooking(this.value);">
                <span class="add-on" style="height:30px;"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <span class="add-on" style="height:30px;"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input3" value="" /><br/>
            </td>
        </div>
```

I want to set the date of checkOutDate to be same as I choose the checkInDate, however I am not able to do it. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: add datepicker code

Comment: I am able to set the value of checkoutdate through the below mentioned javascript function: function setCheckOutDate(){
  var str1 = document.getElementById("checkInDate").value;
  document.getElementById("checkOutDate").value=str1;
}
but I am not able to shift the calendar which opens up to the future date

Comment: I am very new to javascript coding, I'll be grateful if anyone can share the code as to how to set the checkOutDate

Answer (score 0):

```
.on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#otherdate').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the event **changeDate** on **checkinDate** then update the **checkoutDate** value

P/S: You should use the snippet feature to show your situation, such as below

```js
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
let dateElm1 = $('.datepicker1');
let dateElm2 = $('.datepicker2');
dateElm1.datepicker({});
dateElm2.datepicker({});

dateElm1.on('changeDate', function (data) {
  dateElm2.datepicker('update', data.date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input class="datepicker1" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
<input class="datepicker2" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```